# Multiple dependencies iOS Nativescrips

Tags: ios, cocoapods, nativescript-angular

I am using the pods to generate my application, how could I avoid this error? it is already based on the installed plugins

1. nativescript-imagepicker
2. @nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus

[!] There are multiple dependencies with different sources for `QBImagePickerController` in `Podfile`:

- QBImagePickerController (from `https://github.com/flypapertech/QBImagePicker.git`, commit `47aa21d32f8e6db0df79b089ad64e43d498b5951`)
- QBImagePickerController (~> 3.4.0)
  'pod install' command failed.

Comment: did you resolved this issue?

Comment: not solve the problem

Comment: node_module comment pod nativescript-imagepicker solutions